# angularjs list box value selection

Tags: angularjs

```
<select multiple ng-multiple="true" class="form-control 
   emailReminder width-169" ng-if="checked" ng-model="selectedReminder" 
   ng-options="x as x.title for x in emailReminderList" value="{{x.id}}">
 </select>
```

I am not able to get the selected value from list in angularjs in controller.js
Please suggest the code to get the selected array value to push it into new array when submit the page

Comment: what you had tried so far?

Comment: <select multiple="multiple" id="idSelect" class="form-control emailReminder width-169" ng-if="checked"  ng-model="selectedReminder" ng-options="x as x.title for x in emailReminderList">
                                 </select>

Comment: I am trying to use like this$scope.saveReminder = function () {
        debugger;
        var list = [];
        //var selected = $('#idSelect option:selected');
        var selected = document.getElementById('idSelect');
        for (var i = 0; i < selected.options.length; i++) {
            if (selected.options[i].selected == true) {
                list.push(selected.options[i]);
            }
        }
       or
        $scope.selectedReminder = $scope.emailReminderList;

Comment: Please don't post this as a comment, but edit your question and add the information there.

Comment: don't use `document.getElementById` in angular use scope to access element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="idSelect" class="form-control emailReminder width-169" 
  ng-if="checked" ng-model="selectedReminder" 
  ng-options="x as x.title for x in emailReminderList"> 
</select>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.saveReminder = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.selectedReminder, function($value, $key) {
        $scope.list.push($value.title);
    });
    console.log($scope.list);
};
```

Comment: Hi tried to use this but not getting $value on controller

Comment: HI plz Post JSon Format